# How/Can I dynamically set Contexts in CircleCi

Tags: circleci

I have a circle CI environment in which I'd like to assign context dynamically to deploy to 4 different environments.

Ideally I'd like to set the context using a pipeline parameter, any ideas how I can achieve this?

Example how I'd expect to achieve this:

```
parameters:
  test-contxt:
    type: string
    default: "staging"

build-test-on-prod-pr:
    jobs:
      - build-api:
          context:
            - "<< pipeline.parameters.test-context >>"
      - test-api:
          context:
            - "<< pipeline.parameters.test-context >>"
      - deploy-api:
          context:
            - "<< pipeline.parameters.test-context >>"
```

Trying this approach results in this error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Error calling workflow: 'build-test-on-prod-pr'
# Unknown variable(s): test-context
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the sample I posted in my question does actually work, the mistake I was making was a typo in the parameter. However I'll leave this question up just in case its helpful. I also removed the quotes, but I don't think that matters.

```
parameters:
  test-context:
    type: string
    default: "staging"

build-test-on-prod-pr:
    jobs:
      - build-api:
          context:
            - << pipeline.parameters.test-context >>
      - test-api:
          context:
            - << pipeline.parameters.test-context >>
      - deploy-api:
          context:
            - << pipeline.parameters.test-context >>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the typo?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, I did edit the question at some point and changed the code before I managed to get it working. 

1.  The question originally posted used code copy pasted from my 1st attempt

2.  Made some changes locally and got a different error (unknown variables)

3.  Updated my question with changes + new error. Likely did this manually without copy pasting so didn't duplicate my typo from local config to the post

4.  Realised the second issue was a typo, but the config I had provided served as a correct example for the question I'd asked originally

Comment: I appreciate that this makes the post a little confusing, do you think it would be helpful to change the example in the question to include the typo that I had made in the original question?

Comment: Yeah, I think it would. As right now, both the question and answer have the same code. OR whatever info you feel is needed for the question.